# How to get profile tab in VisualVM cross-platform?

Tags: java, cross-platform, profile, visualvm

Target to profile is an ARM 32-bit:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

My development machine is a crapbook running a totally different arch, bits, JVM etc, but VisualVM is running as:

```
Java: 1.8.0_112; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b16, mixed mode)
```

My problem is that I don't have the profile tab that I want, although I do have the sampler tab (which I don't want to use).

I have all following debug and JMX -D arguments on my target machine:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.223.64.109
```

Can anyone suggest why I'm not getting the profile tab?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I've answered my own question now, after finding this nugget on: https://visualvm.java.net/applications_remote.html

[image: clip from visualvm website]

From other research, it looks like VisualVM and a local JVM communicate using files that are dropped in the java.io.tmp directory. Files with local process IDs are dropped. Maybe profile data is too vast to be transported over a network, or that the profiling procedure needs the timeliness of something being written to file by the JVM and observed immediately by VisualVM.